# Load only struct from map's value from an avro file into a Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

Using PySpark, I need to load "Properties" object (map's value) from an avro file into its own Spark dataframe. Such that, "Properties" from my avro file will become a dataframe with its elements and values as columns and rows. Hence, struggling to find some clear examples accomplishing that.

Schema of the file:

```
root
 |-- SequenceNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Offset: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EnqueuedTimeUtc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SystemProperties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- member0: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- member1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- member2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- member3: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- Properties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- member0: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- member1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- member2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- member3: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- Body: binary (nullable = true)
```

The resulting "Properties" dataframe loaded from the above avro file needs to be like this:

| member0 | member1 | member2 | member3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value | value | value | value |

Answer (score 2):

[`map_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_values.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_values) is your friend.

> Collection function: Returns an unordered array containing the values of the map.
> New in version 2.3.0.

```py
df_properties = df.select((F.map_values(F.col('Properties'))[0]).alias('vals')).select('vals.*')
```

Full example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 20, 4.5, 'r', b'8')],
    ['key', 'member0', 'member1', 'member2', 'member3'])
df = df.select(F.create_map('key', F.struct('member0', 'member1', 'member2', 'member3')).alias('Properties'))
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- Properties: map (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- key: string
#  |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- member0: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- member1: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- member2: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- member3: binary (nullable = true)

df_properties = df.select((F.map_values(F.col('Properties'))[0]).alias('vals')).select('vals.*')

df_properties.show()
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |member0|member1|member2|member3|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |     20|    4.5|      r|   [38]|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+

df_properties.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- member0: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- member1: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- member2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- member3: binary (nullable = true)
```